# i have the error following and i need help please

Tags: java, spring-boot

Error description:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot invoke "com.example.produits.service.StabiliteService.saveStabilite(com.example.produits.entities.Stabilite)" because "this.stabiliteService" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.produits.service.StabiliteService.saveStabilite(com.example.produits.entities.Stabilite)" because "this.stabiliteService" is null
```

controller class

```java
@Controller
public class StabiliteController {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private StabiliteService stabiliteService;

    @RequestMapping("/createStabilite")
    public String createStabilite(ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("stabilite", new Stabilite());
        modelMap.addAttribute("mode", "new");
        return "formStabilite";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/saveStabilite")
    public String saveStabilite(@Valid Stabilite stabilite, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return "formStabilite";

        stabiliteService.saveStabilite(stabilite);
        return "formStabilite";
    }
```

service class:

```java
@Service
public interface StabiliteService {

    Stabilite saveStabilite(Stabilite s);

    Stabilite updateStabilite(Stabilite s);

    void deleteStabilite(Stabilite s);

    void deleteStabiliteById(Long id);

    Stabilite getStabilite(Long id);

    List<Stabilite> getAllStabilites();

    List<Stabilite> findByLibelleStabilite(String libelle);

    Page<Stabilite> getAllStabillitesParPage(int page, int size);
}
```

Comment: For some reason, `stabiliteService` has not been wired, and is `null`.  Note that since you explicitly said `required = false` you don't get an error for the wiring failure.  But the flip-side is that if you are going to do that, your code should be designed to "work" in the case that `stabiliteService` is `null`.  (Hmmm is that a typo?  Do you maybe mean `stabilizeService`?  What is a "stabilite"???)

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is **StabiliteService** in correct package to read all components?
Try with below annotation with @SpringBootApplication

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={
        "com.your.package.name", 
        "com.your.another.package.name"
})
```

Comment: @Christ Assemien 
Worked?

Comment: I still have no result

Comment: Which class implements StabiliteService  interface?
Add @ Service annotation on that Implemented class.
Remove @ Service annotation from interface.

Comment: Thanks @ParthPatel  it's working now

Comment: Great, you can mark this as answer.